# HTML/CSS pseudo-element move to the next line after content remove

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am learning HTML + CSS and I am trying write console simulator in HTML/CSS. I have problem with pseudo-element ::after. I have `<pre class="commands" contenteditable id="0"></pre>`, what is editable line to write commands. I can click on this line and write something, but when i write something e.g. "a" and remove it, my "prompt" (i think it's good word in English) goes to the next line, but it should stay. How to prevent this?

My code:

> ERROR 404

Comment: I always see it on new line, even when i remove

Comment: I added screenshoots what i mean.

Comment: yes, but still didnt see any problem,  i typed `a` then remove it, nothing happened, it stay on same line. do you see this problem on this demo?

Comment: yes, i have. Do you have this animated prompt always on the same line, even when you typed something and then remove it?

Comment: yes, using `chrome` are you using chrome? or? UPDATE: i checked with ff, i saw the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i found cause of your problem, `firefox` add a `<br>` in your `<pre>` tag, i have no idea why, it not happend in `chrome` anyway, your quick solution is:

```
pre br {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line=0;
  var type=document.getElementById(line); 
  var currentIndex=0;

var start=function(text){
  currentIndex=0;
  var interval=setInterval(function(){
    if(text.length>currentIndex){
      type.textContent+=text[currentIndex];
      currentIndex++;
    }
    else{clearInterval(interval);}
  },100
  );
}

//start("How are you today?");

$(document).keypress(function(e){
  console.log(e.keyCode);
    switch(e.keyCode){
      case 13: newLine(); break;
      case 38: start(" Mateusz."); break;}
});

var newLine=function(){
  line++;
  $("#console").append('<div class="prompt">$</div><pre class="commands" id="'+line+'"></pre>');
  type=document.getElementById(line);
}
});
```

```css
*{
  border: 1px dashed gold;
}

pre br {
    display: none;
}

#console{
  background-color: black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 10px solid silver;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.prompt{
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
}

.prompt::before{
  content: 'root@xubuntu ~ ';
  color: lime;
}

.commands{
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.commands::after{
  content: "|";
  color: white;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  /*border: 1px solid white;*/
  animation-name: ps1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  display: inline;
}

@keyframes ps1{
  from{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

[contenteditable]:focus {
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console">
  <div class="prompt">$</div>
  <pre class="commands" contenteditable id="0"></pre>
</div>
```